# I want to warp text in a custom shape but I don't want it to be distorted

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-wrap

In the logo I'm making, there is a circle which has text wrapped around it on the upper half. I used the warp tool but it distorts the text and doesn't give the desired effect.

I can't use the type on path tool because that is not the effect I want.

I want the individual letters to be straight and the only way I can think of doing that is to mannually edit each letter to sit around the circle. I was wondering if there was another, more efficient way to fo that.

Comment: So you want letters to follow the path of the circle but keep each letter facing upwards and not towards the center of the circle?

Comment: Yes, basically. Also the sizes of the letters need to be different.

Comment: Before you complained about distortion did you actually set the envelope tool to not simplify the result as this usually destroys the feel

Answer (score 8):

Here a solution, you should make some vector retouches at the end for sure.

- Make as many vertical rectangles as letters your logo has
- Make the circle, in the image it is semi-transparent just to show the intersection with the rectangles
- Select all the rectangles, **Menu Object** > **Compound Path** > **Make**
- Select the rectangles and the circle, from the **Pathfinder Panel** apply **Minus Front**
- To this shape  **Menu Object** > **Compound Path** > **Release**
- To this shape  **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Transform the bottom points to the left and right shapes to  **Corner Points** to avoid extreme distortion: selecting each, from the **Top Options Panel** click on **Convert Selected Anchor Point to Smooth** first and **Convert Selected Anchor Point to Corner** after.

[image: points]

- To the text, **Menu Type** > **Create Outlines**
- To this outlined text **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Select the first letter together with the first shape, **Menu Object** > **Envelope Distort** > **Make with Top Object**
- Do the same with the other letters and shapes

[image: gif]

- Once it's done, **Menu Object** > **Expand** to enable the vector work on each letter
- For fixing the left and right bottom strokes, this depends on the used letters, use the same circle with an outside stroke the same size as the letter stroke
- Expand appearance
- Select the circle togheter with the letter, activate the **Shape Builder Tool** and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, delete the surplus polygons

  [image: END]

Result:

[image: LOGO]

Comment: Thank you for the help. For some reason, the website isn't letting me upload an image. But what I want is for the upper margin of the text to be one straight horizontal line and the lower margin to wrap around the circle. The letters will vary in size accordingly. Using your example, the letter L will be larger along with the letter S. The letter T at the centre will be the smallest and so on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on step 7 a bit more? I am unable to go through with that step.

Comment: @chocol8mousse Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

I found something that may lead to your solution. If you look at "[Text warping with envelope distortion](https://layersmagazine.com/illustrator-text-envelope-distortion.html)," I've discovered that it accomplishes much of your requirements.

The example provided describes creating the text and converting it to outlines. A rectangle is then created around the text, followed by both objects being selected.

Object, Envelope Distort, Make with top object.

The linked example distorts the rectangle in various ways, none of which involve a circle.

I created a circle to use as a guide, but is not integral to the distortion, added a few anchor points to the rectangle and warped the rectangle to approximate the top half of the circle.

The result is thus:

[image: text around circle]

The stair stepping feature is pretty slick, something I learned new today, but doesn't address the varying change of letter height. I would not suggest that my example is a perfect example, but it provides a method of some value. I should have used all caps to allow for a uniform top line as you've described in your comment.

I added only one anchor point on the bottom of the rectangle. I would expect far less distortion with additional anchor points to better adjust the text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used this feature and it resulted in the same distorted look which I don't want. Something did come to my mind on seeing this though. I wonder if I make a shape with steps on the bottom instead of a curve and use the envelope tool, I'll get the desired effect.

Comment: It would be interesting to combine these two answers and discover that your objective is accomplished.