# Strange Result of "Envelope Distort : Make with Top Object"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I used pen tool to make the desired shape and would like to have my text adjusted in that shape (I tried this out on an older version of illustrator and it works fine but I am having problem with Illustrator CC (2017) Mac)

It distorts the letters and makes them really weird... to the point that it's not even recognisable as a word.

[image]

I am trying to add "Lorem Ipsum" in the upper lip area.
I've tried words of different length and and various shapes too but it's not working.
I've even tried keeping the word on the shape I want and different fonts and sizes.. still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the shape angle to 0º, and after the distortion put it back to the original position.

[image: distort]

Comment: thank you for this!! It worked for me for this particular shape... when I tried it on another shape it did work but didn't work as efficiently it works here... my letters keep getting distorted from the middle and don't get placed according to the shape entirely.. like edges remain untouched and there is a significant amount of space between the letter and the shape's circumference (apologies if I am using lay-man language; I am new to illustrator but need to get it done ASAP)

Comment: Making an Envelope Distortion for a text or a whole word is not the best way to do this kind of job. You will always get unwanted results. My recommendation is making it by letter or small group of letters. Maybe [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110570/120647) can help.