# How to create distorted, textured, type in a specific shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typography, vintage

there is a great designer that create awesome stuff like that using typodesign. I really love him.

[image]
Some of you guys have any idea of how I can obtain the same result of text envelope without distort the text? (if I use envelope distort in illustrator the font often gets horrible).
In this case, instead, everything seems to be perfect. I don't wanna imagine that is handmade... 
Thanks in advice folks!

Comment: Try **Envelope Distort** to each character like it's showed in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110570/120647)

Comment: In all probability it may be 30% automated to get basic shapes via envelopes.... then it *is* "handmade" from that point. You may do better by describing what software you are familiar with. Or what software you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks Scott!
I think that the better way to make this was Illustrator. I'm using that